# Script with renaming files in terminal

Tags: string, bash, path, file-rename, zenity

I am writing a script in bash to manage files. I need to add a functionality to change files name. To get a file I use zenity File Selection Dialog. After this operation I have a variable with path to this file: `/home/user/Desktop/name_of_file`. How can I remove current file name from this string and put there a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bash‘s [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
name="/home/user/Desktop/name_of_file"
new="${name%/*}/new_name_of_file"
echo "$new"
```

Output:

```
/home/user/Desktop/new_name_of_file
```